# Dimension of space $D(\Omega)$

Tags: distribution-theory

The space of all infinitely differentiable functions with compact support in region $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, is not trivial for any $\Omega$, and it is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, I denote it with $D(\Omega)$(I do not here care about topology)(who likes to distinguish things let him/her take $C_0^{+\infty}$ or $C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$, that is not the point here), and, like any other vector space, it must have a basis and a dimension. So, the most normal question would be what is the dimension of that vector space.

My guess, which I do not know if it is true, is that it should be infinity, because if we take $(a,b)$(for example) and now for some $(a_1,b_1)\subset (a,b)$, $(a_1,b_1) \neq (a,b)$, there is an $\epsilon > 0$ , where $\epsilon = max\{|a-a_1|,|b-b_1|\}$, and now we can take function $f$ to be any polynomial in $[a_1,b_1]$, that function $f$ satisfies that for $x \in (a,a_1)$ holds $f(x)<f(a_1)$, and for $x \in (b_1,b)$, it holds $f(x) < f(b_1)$, $f$ is on $(a,a+\frac{\epsilon}{3})$ and on $(b-\frac{\epsilon}{3}, b)$ always zero, and $f \in C^{\infty}(a,b)$, and this function exists and is in $D(a,b)$, so basically this is why it should be infinity. But, I do not know if any of this has any nonempty intersection with something which would be true. Thanks for help!

Comment: You're using $D(\Omega)$ as a notation for all $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ functions, or the $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ compactly supported functions?

Comment: I thought I made everything clear, but I forgot. So, the point is all the infinitely differentiable functions with compact support.

Comment: Sorry, I am retarded.... Thanks, @OpenBall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a standard result that for any real sequence $\{a_n\}$ there exists a function $\varphi\in D(\Bbb R)$ such that $$\forall n\ge 0 \quad \varphi^{(n)}(0)=a_n.$$
By a slight modification of this result you can see that the space of test functions on any non-empty open interval is infinite-dimensioned.

A somewhat harder exercise would be to show that the basis of this space has cardinality of at least continuum (the argument above shows that the basis is at least countable).

Comment: please just tell me where to read proof for that fact for all sequences {a_n}, there is a function $\phi$ such that $\phi^{(n)} (0)=a_n$